# Bullet Chart: Can't get the d3.scale().linear().domain() right for each element in data array

Tags: javascript, d3.js, axis

Trying to rebuild Mike Bostock's basic bullet chart example from the ground up, in order to understand what is going on.

Stuck at the point where I establish the domain, in order to get a different scale and axis ticks for each chart.

Temporarily set the domain to [0, 35], but what I really want is different domains for each individual chart, following the formula: .domain([0, semaine[x].disponibilite]).

**Code and chart:** [bl.ock](http://bl.ocks.org/jean-Phil/d8be62c4e44d80cac288)

...a simplification of objects array:

```
var semaine = [{"individu":"Stefan", "disponibilite": 28, "totalAffectations": 25},
{"individu":"Geneviève","disponibilite": 32, "totalAffectations": 14},
{"individu":"Marie","disponibilite": 35},
{"individu":"David","disponibilite": 40}];
```

...The line I can't seem to get right.

```
var disponibiliteScale = d3.scale.linear()
    **.domain([0, 35])**
    .range([0, width]);
```

Tried several ways, but I can't seem to get it right. Help would be most welcome... Thanks!

Comment: `.domain([0, d3.max(semaine, function(d) { return d.disponibilite; })])`

Comment: Thank you very much, Lars, for your reply.  However, this function does not return what I expect.  Allow me to clarify... I would like independent domains for each chart, ie. the _first_ chart to have a domain of 28, the _second_ chart fo have a domain of 32, the _third_, 35, and the _fourth_, 40.

Comment: Well then it would be just `.domain([0, semaine[i].disponibilite])`, where `i` denotes the current chart.

Comment: Hello Lars.  Thank you for writing again. I really wish it were that simple, but for some reason I don't understand, that breaks the scale.  I updated the code, you can have a look... _no more ticks!_

Comment: Ah, well your code here and your code in your example are different. You need `d3.max(semaine[i].disponibilite)` to work with an array.